# Fortify and source code repositories

Tags: configuration, repository, fortify

I am starting with HP Fortify SCA and I want to know how connect it to a source code repository. I read and look for how to integrate it but I didn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using Jenkins (https://jenkins-ci.org/) to download your code from a repository and then call HP Fortify from Jenkins.  You could even use Jenkins to trigger automatic analysis with HP Fortify whenever it detects a new version or once a day/week/month.

Comment: Hi Syslog, this was my very first thought and probably at the end I will use it, but first I want to try if Fortify can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Fortify does not natively make a direct connection to the repo.  The code has to be local to the scan so that it can be cleaned, translated, and compiled.

Jenkins could probably do it like @Syslog said, but personally I wouldn't until you are very familiar with how Fortify runs against your codebase.  If you are just getting started with Fortify, run it manually for a few months until you learn its (many, many ) quirks.